# VB.NET Web Browser Control

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

When I use the Web Browser control with VB.NET and navigated to a site it said 'outdated Web Browser'. When I use Internet Explorer the site loads fine. I thought the Web Browser control used the latest version of Internet Explorer installed on the machine? I really need this site to load with the Web Browser control so I can manipulate it and use API functions. Is there some advanced Web Browser control I can use that will work better?

Comment: Could you provide the version of .NET you're using, as well as the version of IE you have installed?

Comment: I'm using VS Ultimate 2013 with the 4.5 Framework. I have Internet Explorer 11 installed.

Comment: What's the number returned from the `Version` property on an instance of the control? That would give you the version of IE it's using.

Comment: Can you also tell us the url you are going to?

Comment: Cory - I'll check the the version property and see. Matt - I can't say what site I'm going to but it works with IE, Firefox, Chrome, ect.

Comment: I'm just gonna have go the old school way and use the API with the currently opened window. Thanks for comments though.

Answer (score 1):

By default webbrowser control uses IE 7 if the version of the IE in that machine is IE7 or above. Please check your site in IE7 browser.